# Laravel 6 user not being redirected after password has been reseted

Tags: laravel

After the user has clicked on the password reset url and entered his or hers new password nothing happens after the form is posted. The page just loads and never redirects the user.

Looking into Telescope I can see the POST request **/password/reset** returns **302** with the following respons **"Redirected to https://mysite.test/account"**

In my `ResetPasswordController` I have added `protected $redirectTo = '/account';` but it still doesnt work. The page just loads forever without redirecting the user so you have to manually refresh the page or visit /account page since the password reset actually worked but it just never redirected the user

Comment: Check the laravel/php error logs. Maybe headers have already been sent.

Comment: Does your route url work if you try to go there directly?

Comment: @BramVerstraten Could not find anything, and no exceptions either

Comment: @MrEvers Yea it does, it has the web,auth,verified middlewares but should still work since the reset password also logs in the user

Comment: Only thing that comes to mind is to override the redirect with returning the logged in user or other variables, to see if they are correctly set after the pass reset. Dirty, but still the most surefire way to see at which point the code breaks.

Comment: Is working original `ResetPasswordController.php` for redirect to `/home` ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I had to change `{{ csrf_field() }}` into `@csrf` in my blade teplate file and now it works perfectly